# In protractor, how do I return a value from a function back to the "it block"

Tags: javascript, function, protractor, return, undefined

I have a function to read from an Excel file. I am unable to return the results to the “it block” where they will be used. Instead I get the dreaded “undefined”. Console.log shows that the data was retrieved correctly. I'm relatively new to node.js/protractor and online examples have not helped.

The spreadsheet is structured as:

```
|testcase | baseUrl         | userName | passWord | profileNumber |
|1        | http://web1.com | apple    | orange   | 12345         |
|2        | http://web2.com | ford     | mustang  | 23456         |
|3        | http://web3.com | canine   | collie   | 34567         |
```

Here's the code:

```js
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var wrkbook = new Excel.Workbook();
var filename = './testData.xlsx';
var sheet = 'Sheet1';
    
describe('Read XL Data', function () {
    it('Get URL', function () {
        console.log(getCellData(2, 'baseUrl'));
    })

    function getCellData(rowNum, colName) {
        var Excel = require('exceljs');
        var filename = './testData.xlsx';
        var sheet = 'Sheet1';
        var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

        workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename).then(function () {
            var workSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheet);
            var totalRows = workSheet.actualRowCount;
            var totalCols = workSheet.actualColumnCount;
            console.log("total number of rows : " + totalRows)
            console.log("total number of cols : " + totalCols)
            // search for the specified column name
            for (i = 1; i <= totalCols; i++) {
                currCol = i;
                var cellValue = workSheet.getRow(1).getCell(i).toString();
                //console.log("Column # '" + i + "' : " + cellValue)
                if (cellValue === colName) {
                    //console.log("cellValue " + cellValue);
                    //console.log("colName " + colName); 
                    console.log("Column (" + currCol + ") is named: " + cellValue + " and Row (" + rowNum + ") contains: " + workSheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(currCol).toString());
                    browser.controlFlow().execute(function () {
                        var result = workSheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(currCol).toString();
                        expect(result).not.toBeNull;
                        return result;
                    })
                }
                else {
                    //console.log('cellValue: ' + cellValue + ' - colName: ' + colName)
                }  
            }  
        })  
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
C:\Automation\PPR>protractor Init.js
[07:39:48] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[07:39:48] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
undefined
total number of rows : 5
total number of cols : 33
Column (2) is named: baseUrl and Row (2) contains: http://web2.com

1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 3.476 seconds
[07:39:56] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[07:39:56] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed'
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your function `getCellData` doesn't return anything.

Your mistake that you think when you call `return result;` it will pass the value up to the wrapping function, but it's only valid on the scope of `browser.controlFlow()`

So based on the assumption that your function REALLY does what it should do inside, in order to return the value you need to do this

```
function getCellData(rowNum, colName) {
  var Excel = require('exceljs');
  var filename = './testData.xlsx';
  var sheet = 'Sheet1';
  var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

  return workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename).then(function () { // <------- that needs to be returned too
    var workSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheet);
    var totalRows = workSheet.actualRowCount;
    var totalCols = workSheet.actualColumnCount;
    console.log("total number of rows : " + totalRows)
    console.log("total number of cols : " + totalCols)
    // search for the specified column name
    for (i = 1; i <= totalCols; i++) {
      currCol = i;
      var cellValue = workSheet.getRow(1).getCell(i).toString();
      //console.log("Column # '" + i + "' : " + cellValue)
      if (cellValue === colName) {
        return workSheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(currCol).toString(); // <----------
      } else {
        //console.log('cellValue: ' + cellValue + ' - colName: ' + colName)
      }  
    }  
  })  
}
```

See how I have 2 return statements?

Comment: Thanks Sergey!  I used your suggestion but still receive "undefined" when code is executed.  Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @Andrew I don't know what `browser.controlFlow().execute(function () {` supposed to do, so you can try to simply return your value. I updated the code in the answer^^

Comment: Thanks (again) Sergey!  Unfortunately, I get the same "undefined" result. I will continue to research the issue (it seems like it should be so simple).

Comment: oh right right right, I missed something too, one more `return`, I'm updating the answer